# WinForms: Paint outside parent control's bounds

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I have inherited my class from DataGridViewColumn to show an multi-line textbox for displaying and editing lengthy text. I have used the same method as shown in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx. The only problem is that in Microsoft's example, the DateTimePicker draws perfectly fine even if it needs to go outside the boundary of the parent DataGridView (e.g. if the cell is in the last row of the grid), but in my case, my editing control cuts off or clips and doesn't draw outside the DataGridView. I have already tried expanding clip rectangle in PositionEditingControl, but that doesn't help. I also see that Microsoft's example doesn't do anything special with the clip bounds to do this. Anyone knows how to deal with it?

Comment: Well, DateTimePicker cannot color outside of the lines either.  It is the month calendar popup that can.  It is a top-level window.  You'd need to create your own top-level popup window in Winforms by using a borderless Form with the TextBox docked as fill.

Comment: Thanks a ton Hans. Sometimes we just can't see the obvious. This is actually the answer to my question, but I'm not sure how to mark a comment as answer.